# How do I set my DataGridView control to AutoSize according to number of Rows?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` control, which is inside of a `GroupBox`.

`GroupBoxdock` is fill.

I am showing some data inside `DataGridView` and want to change its size according to number of rows in the `DataGridView`.

The number of rows are not constant.

There is no control below this `DataGridView` .

Comment: Enable scrolls in grid view

Comment: you  want the Row.Height to change. You need to do that in a loop.  but what will happen when the number of Rows is too large and the rows get too small to display theit content??

Comment: @Sinatr: Not a duplicate!

Comment: on that time gridview dock property can be change into fill

Comment: Well, the there is even a little more logic you need to code.